# Uncaught Error: Unexpected value 'AngularFireAuth' imported by the module 'AppModule'. Please add a @NgModule annotation

Tags: angular, typescript, firebase

im having this issue that has been troubling me for a while now. I'm trying to implement firebase authenticaton into a service and use an auth.guard for routing and so on, and i am getting this error.

[The error at hand](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qxMPm.png)

Auth guard:

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { AngularFireAuth } from 'angularfire2/auth';

import { CanActivate, ActivatedRouteSnapshot, RouterStateSnapshot, Router } from '@angular/router';
import { AuthService } from './auth.service';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs/Observable';
import 'rxjs/add/operator/take';
import 'rxjs/add/operator/map';
import 'rxjs/add/operator/do';

@Injectable()
export class AuthGuard implements CanActivate {
  constructor(private authService: AuthService, private afAuth: AngularFireAuth, private router: Router) { }

  canActivate(
    next: ActivatedRouteSnapshot,
    state: RouterStateSnapshot): Observable<boolean> | boolean {

    return this.afAuth.authState
        .take(1)
        .map(user => !!user)
        .do(loggedIn => {
          if (!loggedIn) {
            console.log('access denied');
            this.router.navigate(['/login']);
          } else {
            this.router.navigate(['/dashboard']);
          }
        });
  }
}
```

Auth service:

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { Router } from '@angular/router';

import { BehaviorSubject } from 'rxjs/BehaviorSubject';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs/Observable';
import { AngularFireAuth } from 'angularfire2/auth';
import * as firebase from 'firebase/app';


@Injectable()
export class AuthService {
  private loggedIn = new BehaviorSubject<boolean>(false);
  user: Observable<firebase.User>;

  get isLoggedIn() {
    return this.loggedIn.asObservable();
  }

  constructor(private router: Router, private firebaseAuth: AngularFireAuth) {
    this.user = firebaseAuth.authState;
  }

  login(userName: string, password: string) {
    this.firebaseAuth
      .auth
      .signInWithEmailAndPassword(userName, password)
      .then(value => {
        console.log('Uspesno logovanje');
      })
      .catch(err => {
        console.log('Neuspesno logovanje: ', err.message);
      });
  }

  logout() {
    this.firebaseAuth
      .auth
      .signOut();
  }

}
```

app module

```
import { HttpClientModule } from '@angular/common/http';
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { ReactiveFormsModule } from '@angular/forms';
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { BrowserAnimationsModule } from '@angular/platform-browser/animations';
import { NguiMapModule } from '@ngui/map';
import { AngularFireModule } from 'angularfire2';
import { AngularFireAuthModule } from 'angularfire2/auth';
import { AngularFireDatabaseModule } from 'angularfire2/database';
import { FormsModule } from '@angular/forms';

import { environment } from './../environments/environment';
import { AppMaterialModule } from './app-material/app-material.module';
import { AppRoutingModule } from './app-routing.module';
import { AppComponent } from './app.component';
import { AuthGuard } from './auth/auth.guard';
import { AuthService } from './auth/auth.service';
import { ContactComponent } from './contact/contact.component';
import { DashboardComponent } from './dashboard/dashboard.component';
import { FooterComponent } from './footer/footer.component';
import { HomeComponent } from './home/home.component';
import { IconsComponent } from './icons/icons.component';
import { LoginComponent } from './login/login.component';
import { MapComponent } from './map/map.component';
import { NavbarComponent } from './navbar/navbar.component';
import { NotificationsComponent } from './notifications/notifications.component';
import { SidebarComponent } from './sidebar/sidebar.component';
import { TableComponent } from './table/table.component';
import { UserComponent } from './user/user.component';

@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    AppComponent,
    LoginComponent,
    DashboardComponent,
    HomeComponent,
    FooterComponent,
    SidebarComponent,
    NavbarComponent,
    ContactComponent,
    IconsComponent,
    UserComponent,
    TableComponent,
    MapComponent,
    NotificationsComponent,
  ],
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    ReactiveFormsModule,
    BrowserAnimationsModule,
    AppMaterialModule,
    HttpClientModule,
    AppRoutingModule,
    NguiMapModule.forRoot({ apiUrl: 'https://maps.google.com/maps/api/js?key=<MY_API_KEY>' }),
    AngularFireModule.initializeApp(environment.firebase),
    AngularFireDatabaseModule,
    AngularFireAuthModule,
    FormsModule
  ],
  providers: [AuthService, AuthGuard],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule { }
```

I added some changes, before i did, login was working with email credentials that i specified on the firebase console, but the routing was off, so i tried to fix it and i ended up breaking it even more.

Comment: Edit and add your source code

Comment: Edited, please have a look now :)

Comment: Care to add code for AppModule? I suspect you are missing `AngularFireAuthModule` inside the `imports` section in `AppModule`.

Comment: Nope, i have it..

Comment: Can you please add that code so that we have more info.This issue sometimes arises when there's a conflict between the versions of firebase and angularFire